# set proxy permanently for installing packages by pycharm

Tags: python, pip, pycharm

my PyCharm is behind proxy server.

HTTP Proxy in System Settings (PyCharm) is ok.

But I can't install packages (Python Interpreter -> Install -> Available Packages) because the command executed is pip install package_to_install.

If I add --proxy=http://myproxy:port in Options (of the selected package) no problem ... I can install package (because the command executed is pip install package_to_install --proxy=http://myproxy:port).

But I would like to avoid adding each time --proxy option.

Can I set --proxy option permanently?

Take care. Best regards.

paco